# Percentage on SMB Extraction on Wireshark

Tags: wireshark, smb

What does the percentage means in this image ?

Can i assume that this network has re-transmission problems? They are usual or this really means a problematic network ?

The path to access this was in Wireshark > File > Export Objects > SMB.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [SMB object export feature](https://bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4451) was developed by Jose Pico. It's described in the White Paper: [A tool for capturing SMB files with Wireshark](http://www.taddong.com/docs/WP_SMBPlugin.pdf) by David Perez & Jose Pico.

The definition of percentage is given by:

> [% captured]:  percentage  reflecting how  much  of  the  file  was actually captured. It may show “!mem” value if the file doesn’t fit into memory.

According to this definition, the screenshot in your question doesn't indicate any network problem but just that Wireshark has partially captured some of the listed SMB objects.